# How to open Aster Strongboxes in Kingdom of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I searched internet for an answer but all I found was that I need to find a gravestone that gives me "half an amulet" which then starts a questline that will reward me a key to these chests.

What is the name of the quest line and where can I find these gravestones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Name of the quest line is **The Aster Inheritance**.

**Heric Aster's Grave**

Heric Aster's Grave is located South, South-West of Helmgard Keep, against the Western base of Skycrown mountain.

**Bodan Aster's Grav**

Bodan Aster's Grave is located South of Dolve Wayle in the Tala-Rane section of the Plains of Erathell.

You can find full walkthrough for this quest along with more details about each gravestone location [here](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/The_Aster_Inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some speculation as to where the quest comes from, but I pulled something up.

From what I have gathered it starts by finding one of the two pieces of the amulet. Once you find one the marker will appear to lead you too the other half. It it appears to be titled "The Aster Inheritance"

The quest outline and locations can be found [here](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/The_Aster_Inheritance).

**Location of the grave for those who want it:**

> "Bodan Aster's Grave is located South of Dolve Wayle in the Tala-Rane section of the Plains of Erathell. The grave is particularly difficult to spot due to the fact that it's nestled in a corner on the north side of an old caste wall. There is a bright Edelweiss plant in the same area as the grave which may be easier to spot first. Additionally there is a Tala-Rane Lore stone nearby too." - From the Wiki

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the quest for the aster strongboxes, it started when I picked a gate open in a fort 'corgan hold' which is on the west border of Tala-Rane and picked up a scroll that told me about two amulets, I collected the two amulets and fused them together (use follow map markers) then I received a map showing locations of the boxes and the key to open them. You use the aster map and then view your world map to see the locations of the boxes this is only temporary and you will have to re-use the map if you have a bad memory. :P